# Using AWK To Lookup Data in 2 CSV Files

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I've been trying for 3 days to try and understand how to use AWK to give me the results I'm looking for. Let me start by saying I'm not a programmer, pretty novice at best. I've look at about 30 different ways to do what I want but they're either not exact matches and I have to change things and they don't work or they don't work from the beginning.

**Objective:** To compare 2 CSV files and export data to another CVS file. I need to see if any Mac addresses in either Column 2 or Column 3 in file 1 (titled sampleData) show up Column 2 in file 2 (titled sampleLeases),and then print Column 1 from file 2, the mac address that matches, and Column 1 from file 2.

My issue could stem from my misunderstanding of associative arrays in AWK, but I'm trying to learn on the go and I need help.

I've tried this amongst many other.Sorry for the long posting, I just wanted to be as thorough as possible.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next } {if ($2 in a) print $2,a[$1]}' sampleLeases.csv sampleData.csv
```

Below is a sample set of data.

**sampleLeases.csv**

```
10.1.2.3,00:11:22:33:44:55
10.1.2.4,00:11:22:33:44:56
10.1.2.5,00:11:22:33:44:57
10.1.2.6,00:11:22:33:44:58
10.1.2.7,00:11:22:33:44:59
10.1.2.8,00:11:22:33:44:60
10.1.2.9,00:11:22:33:44:61
10.1.2.10,00:11:22:33:44:62
10.1.2.11,00:11:22:33:44:63
10.1.2.12,00:11:22:33:44:64
10.1.2.13,00:11:22:33:44:65
10.1.2.14,00:11:22:33:44:66
10.1.2.15,00:11:22:33:44:67
10.1.2.16,00:11:22:33:44:68
10.1.2.17,00:11:22:33:44:69
10.1.2.18,00:11:22:33:44:70
10.1.2.19,00:11:22:33:44:71
10.1.2.20,00:11:22:33:44:72
10.1.2.21,00:11:22:33:44:73
```

**sampleData.csv**

```
 comp. name,mac address,mac address 2,os version,S/N,dept.,building,asset number
 bldg1-rm200-01,00:11:22:33:44:55,22:33:44:55:66:77,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-02,11:22:33:44:56:44,00:11:22:33:44:56,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-03,00:11:22:33:44:57,22:33:44:55:66:79,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-04,00:11:22:33:44:58,22:33:44:55:66:80,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-05,11:22:33:44:59:45,00:11:22:33:44:60,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-06,00:11:22:33:44:61,22:33:44:55:66:82,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-07,11:22:33:44:61:45,00:11:22:33:44:62,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-08,00:11:22:33:44:63,22:33:44:55:66:84,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-09,00:11:22:33:44:64,22:33:44:55:66:85,Osversion,98745562,cart,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-10,00:11:22:33:44:65,22:33:44:55:66:86,Osversion,98745562,lab,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-11,11:22:33:44:65:56,00:11:22:33:44:66,Osversion,98745562,lab,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-12,11:22:33:44:66:56,00:11:22:33:44:67,Osversion,98745562,lab,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-13,11:22:33:44:67:20,00:11:22:33:44:68,Osversion,98745562,lab,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-14,11:22:33:44:68:34,00:11:22:33:44:69,Osversion,98745562,lab,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-15,00:11:22:33:44:70,22:33:44:55:66:91,Osversion,98745562,lab,main,6587521336
 bldg1-rm200-16,11:22:33:44:70:59,00:11:22:33:44:71,Osversion,98745562,lab,main,6587521336
```

**Desired Output Format**

```
 bldg1-rm200-01,00:11:22:33:44:55,10.1.2.3
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've tried the both methods suggested by karkafa and Xorg and I'm not receiving any output. I've attached a screenshot showing my Awk version(GNU Awk actually) and Linux kernel version in case it's relevant.I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela to test out my AWK script. [Screenshot showing no AWK output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJn1Q.jpg)

Comment: you're on the right track,  check my answer and try to fix your code.

Comment: @karakfa  Thank you both for taking the time to look at my issue. I seem to have suffering from a bigger issue though I tried using both methods and recieved no output. I've added a screenshot to my original posting.

Comment: and @Xorg, the above statement was intended for both.

Comment: did you verify the order of the files? first data (file2) than lease (file1) for my script.

Comment: @karakfa Yes, I've tried it both ways. I'm going to setup a Centos and probably a FreeBSD VM and try it on those 2 systems as well.

Answer (score 3):

awk to the rescue

```
 $awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=a[$2]=$1;next} $2 in a{print a[$2],$2,$1}' file2 file1
```

will print

```
 bldg1-rm200-01,00:11:22:33:44:55,10.1.2.3
 bldg1-rm200-02,00:11:22:33:44:56,10.1.2.4
 bldg1-rm200-03,00:11:22:33:44:57,10.1.2.5
 bldg1-rm200-04,00:11:22:33:44:58,10.1.2.6
 bldg1-rm200-05,00:11:22:33:44:60,10.1.2.8
 bldg1-rm200-06,00:11:22:33:44:61,10.1.2.9
 bldg1-rm200-07,00:11:22:33:44:62,10.1.2.10
 bldg1-rm200-08,00:11:22:33:44:63,10.1.2.11
 bldg1-rm200-09,00:11:22:33:44:64,10.1.2.12
 bldg1-rm200-10,00:11:22:33:44:65,10.1.2.13
 bldg1-rm200-11,00:11:22:33:44:66,10.1.2.14
 bldg1-rm200-12,00:11:22:33:44:67,10.1.2.15
 bldg1-rm200-13,00:11:22:33:44:68,10.1.2.16
 bldg1-rm200-14,00:11:22:33:44:69,10.1.2.17
 bldg1-rm200-15,00:11:22:33:44:70,10.1.2.18
 bldg1-rm200-16,00:11:22:33:44:71,10.1.2.19
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with some breakdown in codes...
Assuming you have the codes below in a file called `awkscript`

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
#store field two in sampleLeases.csv as mac array 
#store field one in sampleLeases.csv as ip array 
FNR==NR {mac[$2]=$2;ip[$2]=$1;next}
{if($2 in mac){
    print $1,mac[$2],ip[$2]
    }
{if($3 in mac){
    print $1,mac[$3],ip[$3]
    }
}}
```

run script like

```
awk -f awkscript   sampleLeases.csv sampleData.csv
```